# Does testing the statistical significance of an odds ratio always produce a smaller p-value than a z-score obtained from the test of two proportions?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, proportion, z-score, odds

I have a question regarding the significance testing of an adjusted odds ratio vs. the significance testing of the adjusted difference between two proportions using a z-score. This is following the running of a logistic regression. Anecdotally the p-value obtained from testing the odds ratio is smaller, but I don't know if this is a strict rule or changes at some threshold of N. Is there a proof comparing the two, or a quick summary of why they are strictly different/not necessarily strictly different? Thanks in advance.